# Trying to use java 1.6 with app engine gives runtime errors

Tags: google-app-engine

I'm using google app engine java 1.3.4. In eclipse, I set the java compiler to use java 1.6. I don't get any compile errors, but as soon as I try Run As -> Web App I get the following:

> WARNING: failed forwardFilter: java.lang.UnsupportedClassVersionError: Bad version number in .class file
>
> WARNING: failed com.google.apphosting.utils.jetty.DevAppEngineWebAppContext@94b146{/,/Users/me/Desktop/projects/myproject/myproject/eclipse/myproject/war}: java.lang.UnsupportedClassVersionError: Bad version number in .class file
>
> WARNING: failed JettyContainerService$ApiProxyHandler@64f8d4: java.lang.UnsupportedClassVersionError: Bad version number in .class file
>
> WARNING: Error starting handlers
>   java.lang.UnsupportedClassVersionError: Bad version number in .class file
>       at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method)
>       at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:676)
>       at java.security.SecureClassLoader.defineClass(SecureClassLoader.java:124)
>       at java.net.URLClassLoader.defineClass(URLClassLoader.java:260)
>       at java.net.URLClassLoader.access$100(URLClassLoader.java:56)
>       at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:195)
>       at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
>       at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:188)
>       at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:317)
>       at com.google.appengine.tools.development.IsolatedAppClassLoader.loadClass(IsolatedAppClassLoader.java:151)
>       at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:252)
>       at org.mortbay.util.Loader.loadClass(Loader.java:91)
>       at org.mortbay.util.Loader.loadClass(Loader.java:71)
>       at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.Holder.doStart(Holder.java:73)
>       at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.FilterHolder.doStart(FilterHolder.java:81)
>       at org.mortbay.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:50)
>       at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.initialize(ServletHandler.java:662)
>       at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.Context.startContext(Context.java:140)
>       at org.mortbay.jetty.webapp.WebAppContext.startContext(WebAppContext.java:1250)
>       at org.mortbay.jetty.handler.ContextHandler.doStart(ContextHandler.java:517)
>       at org.mortbay.jetty.webapp.WebAppContext.doStart(WebAppContext.java:467)
>       at org.mortbay.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:50)
>       at org.mortbay.jetty.handler.HandlerWrapper.doStart(HandlerWrapper.java:130)
>       at org.mortbay.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:50)
>       at org.mortbay.jetty.handler.HandlerWrapper.doStart(HandlerWrapper.java:130)
>       at org.mortbay.jetty.Server.doStart(Server.java:224)
>       at org.mortbay.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:50)
>       at com.google.appengine.tools.development.JettyContainerService.startContainer(JettyContainerService.java:185)
>       at com.google.appengine.tools.development.AbstractContainerService.startup(AbstractContainerService.java:146)
>       at com.google.appengine.tools.development.DevAppServerImpl.start(DevAppServerImpl.java:222)
>       at com.google.appengine.tools.development.DevAppServerMain$StartAction.apply(DevAppServerMain.java:171)
>       at com.google.appengine.tools.util.Parser$ParseResult.applyArgs(Parser.java:48)
>       at com.google.appengine.tools.development.DevAppServerMain.(DevAppServerMain.java:120)
>       at com.google.appengine.tools.development.DevAppServerMain.main(DevAppServerMain.java:96)
>
> INFO: The server is running at http://localhost:8888/

anyone else getting this? I'm downloading 1.3.5 now but not sure if that's the problem. I'm on a mac 10.5.4

Thank you

Answer (score 1):

If you're on a mac, you need to use Java 1.5 in order for app engine code to compile and run correctly.

Answer (score 0):

You can check which version is required by going into project's properties and then into Project Facets. See this: [image]